# Isolate variables inside a scope in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find how can we isolate variables inside a scope, there is some codes that is easy to write and explain with more variables and helpers, but more variables means more trash to the env......

```
H <- 10
{
#isolated variable "b"
#do something to it to isolate to the current scope
b <- H + 1
H <- b/2
}
#Now b don't exist
print(H)
>> 5.5
```

This is just a simple example, the idea is load `H`, use `b` as a tmp variable inside the scope, and when the scope ends `b` needs to be removed.

Sadly the scopes in R don't clean and isolate variables defined inside them, in the end if we print `b` the result will be 11.

Obvs the use would be in bigger/complex scripts, I know we can use a function, they isolate variables, but in this case I want to skip that option.

Maybe there is other way, and not with scope, I'm open to other ways to keep the env clean.

Thx!

Comment: You could use `local({b <- H + 1; H <<- b/2})` but really would be much better to use a function. If you don't want to save it you don't have to: `H <- (function(x) ({b <- x + 1; b/2}))(H)`. R's a functional language built around closures. That's the best way to create scope.

Comment: @MrFlick I think the OP is looking for `local` - post as answer? The caveats could be explained more fully there.

Comment: I will look a bit more into `new.env()`  or `invisble()` (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#env-basics) depending of the use case.

Comment: @AllanCameron. I'm kind of opposed to actually recommending `local()` for this. I mean it could work but doesn't really seem like a good idea to me. If you want to write up a more complete answer I'd be fine with that.

Comment: :O Great, ```local``` and ```new.env``` works great, sadly can't found how to use ```invisible``` for this case. The ```local``` case, I would like to just point global assignment can be very hard to use, I think ```new.env``` helps better for a clean env.

Comment: @Abs_0_  yep my bad invisible only help if you do not want to display the value but it is still in the environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Wrap the code in `local` with the return value as the last statement and assign the local to H.  both b and the local environment silently disappear.

```
H <- 10
H <- local({
  b <- H + 1
  b/2
})

exists("b")
## [1] FALSE

H
## [1] 5.5
```

**1a)** This could also be written as:

```
H <- 10
local({ b <- H + 1; b/2 }) -> H
```

**2) magrittr** With magrittr this could be done.

```
library(magrittr)

H <- 10
H %<>% { b <- . + 1; b / 2}

exists("b")
## [1] FALSE

H
## [1] 5.5
```

**2a)** or

```
H <- 10
H <- H %>% { b <- . + 1; b / 2}

exists("b")
## [1] FALSE

H
## [1] 5.5
```

**3)  convention** A simple approach is to use the convention that temporary variables begin with dot and then every so often clean them up yourself. `ls()` will not list such variables but `ls(all = TRUE)` will.

```
H <- 10
.b <- H + 1
H <- .b/2

ls() # .b will not be listed but is there
```